# R: Combining several lines and points in one polar plot

Tags: r, plot, polar-coordinates

I have data from several sources describing an y value in a 360 degrees space but I cannot plot them together with a fitted spline on a single polar plot.

Here's some simulated data:

```
# Data for test
set.seed(35)
sim1 <- cbind(rnorm(6,0),seq(0,359,359/5))
sim2 <- cbind(rnorm(9,0),seq(0,359,359/8))
sim3 <- cbind(rnorm(7,0),seq(0,359,359/6))
```

If not doing a polar plot my procedure would be as follows:

```
# Create spline for points
total <- rbind(sim1,sim2,sim3)
fit= smooth.spline(total[,2],total[,1], cv=T)

# Classic solution if not polar plot
plot(sim1[,2],sim1[,1],ylim = c(-3,4), col = "darkgrey")
lines(sim1[,2],sim1[,1], pch=2, col = "darkgrey")
points(sim2[,2],sim2[,1], pch=2, col = "darkgrey")
lines(sim2[,2],sim2[,1], pch=2, col = "darkgrey")
points(sim3[,2],sim3[,1], pch=2, col = "darkgrey")
lines(sim3[,2],sim3[,1], pch=2, col = "darkgrey")
lines(fit, , col = "red")
```

Which would give me this kind of figure:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugz6H.png)

But trying to plot it in a polar plot. I cannot get further than plotting each individually:

```
# Plot
library(plotrix)

polar.plot(sim1[,1],sim1[,2],lwd=3,line.col="red",  radial.lim=c(-3,3),clockwise=TRUE,rp.type = "s")
polar.plot(sim2[,1],sim2[,2],lwd=3,line.col="blue",  radial.lim=c(-3,3),clockwise=TRUE,rp.type = "s")
polar.plot(sim3[,1],sim3[,2],lwd=3,line.col="darkgrey",  radial.lim=c(-3,3),clockwise=TRUE,rp.type = "s")
```

[Poor plot but 360](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXdIs.png)

I have also tried using ggplot2 as well as plotly but nothing yielded what I was hoping for.

Comment: Ah thanks. It is the plotrix library. I will edit this into the main text too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `add` parameter to add lines. Perhaps something like this?

```
polar.plot(sim1[,1], sim1[,2], lwd=1, line.col = "grey20", radial.lim = c(-3,3), 
           clockwise = TRUE, rp.type = "p")
polar.plot(sim2[,1], sim2[,2], lwd=1, line.col = "grey20", radial.lim = c(-3,3), 
           clockwise = TRUE, rp.type = "p", add = TRUE)    
polar.plot(sim3[,1], sim3[,2], lwd=1, line.col = "grey20", radial.lim = c(-3,3), 
           clockwise = TRUE, rp.type = "p", add = TRUE)
polar.plot(fit$y, fit$x, lwd=2, line.col = "firebrick", radial.lim = c(-3,3), 
           clockwise = TRUE, rp.type = "p", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

GGplot alternative:

```
library(ggplot2,ggthemes)

# Data for test
set.seed(35)
sim1 <- cbind(rnorm(6,0),seq(0,359,359/5))
sim2 <- cbind(rnorm(9,0),seq(0,359,359/8))
sim3 <- cbind(rnorm(7,0),seq(0,359,359/6))

# Create spline for points
total <- rbind(sim1,sim2,sim3)

colnames(total)=c('Col1','Col2')
total=as.data.frame(total)
MyNames=c(rep('sim1',nrow(sim1)),rep('sim2',nrow(sim2)),rep('sim3',nrow(sim3)))
total=cbind(MyNames,total)

Radial=ggplot(total)+
  theme_light()+
  geom_line(aes(x=Col2,y=Col1,group=MyNames,colour=MyNames),alpha=0.4)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Col2,y=Col1,group=MyNames,colour=MyNames))+
  geom_line(aes(x=Col2,y=Col1),stat='smooth', method = "loess", span=0.5, alpha=0.4, size=1.2)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,360,by=60),expand=c(0,0),lim=c(0,360))+
  coord_polar(theta='x',start=0)+
  ggtitle('Sim')+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"),legend.text=element_text(size=14),legend.title=element_text(size=14),title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"),plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
Radial
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Axeman. This is almost exactly as I had hoped it to be.

Is it possible to add the spline in something like:
    fitval <- predict(fit, seq(0,360,(360/30)))
    Radial + geom_point(aes(x=fitval$x,y=fitval$y))

Comment: One workaround to my own question is to add "fitval" to the "total" value and name it "fit" or something in the "mynames" value.

Comment: Add variables to the 'total' data frame makes life easier when using ggplot